# check when id is not in table when show bookings

Tags: sql, postgresql

I check if the booking_id is in two tables, when it is in two tables I dont want to show it. My problem is when the booking_id is in one of the two tables it doesnt show it only should hide when it is in both tables (booking_car_status, booking_signature)

```
        SELECT 
        
        booking.id,

        cars.name,
        cars.cover as image,

        car_details.mark,

        client.surname,
        client.lastname
        
        FROM booking

        INNER JOIN cars
        ON booking.car_id = cars.id

        INNER JOIN car_details
        ON car_details.car_id = cars.id

        INNER JOIN client
        ON client.id = booking.client_id
        
        LEFT JOIN booking_car_status
        ON booking_car_status.booking_id = booking.id

        LEFT JOIN booking_signature
        ON booking_signature.booking_id = booking.id

        WHERE booking_car_status.booking_id IS NULL || booking_signature.booking_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Use AND rather than OR in your WHERE clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need `XOR`. You can use `(a is null) <> (b is null)` for this case:

```sql
SELECT 
    booking.id,
    cars.name,
    cars.cover as image,
    car_details.mark,
    client.surname,
    client.lastname
FROM booking
INNER JOIN cars ON booking.car_id = cars.id
INNER JOIN car_details ON car_details.car_id = cars.id
INNER JOIN client ON client.id = booking.client_id
LEFT JOIN booking_car_status ON booking_car_status.booking_id = booking.id
LEFT JOIN booking_signature ON booking_signature.booking_id = booking.id
WHERE (booking_car_status.booking_id IS NULL) <> (booking_signature.booking_id IS NULL);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment but now when both is null it shows nothing, so when both is null or one exists it should show

Comment: @newexe91, sorry it's hard to understand your wording. Try replacing `<>` in my query with `OR`.